# Is there a way to tell whether code is now being compiled as part of a PCH?

Tags: visual-c++

I need to branch a certain statement in a precompiled-header .h file, based on whether the .h is now being used to *create* the PCH (i.e., included in a cpp compiled with /Yc), or now included just to *use* the PCH (i.e., included in a cpp compiled with /Yu).

In other words, I'm looking for something like -

```
#ifdef NOW_CREATING_THE_PCH
  #import yadayada_with_option_a
#else
  #import yadayada_with_option_b
#endif
```

...and can't find anything.
Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks,

-Ofek

[Edit:] The reason I need this is that I use Incredibuild, and have started getting [this warning](http://www.xoreax.com/support_faq.htm#q114). Per the FAQ suggestion, I wish to #import with [no_implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28VS.71%29.aspx#_predir_no_implementation) during PCH creation, and with [implementation_only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28VS.71%29.aspx#_predir_implementation_only) during PCH usage.

Comment: Interesting. Can you tell us the the reason why these need to be different please?

Comment: Certainly - just edited the question.

Comment: IIRC, you can specifically change the configuration (in Visual Studio) of stdafx.cpp (or whatever source file you have that gets compiled with /Yc) to define the symbol NOW_CREATING_THE_PCH. That's not something you get out-of-the-box, but if you need to do it just for one project (or a few), it's not a problem.

Comment: @Boaz - thanks! Embarrassingly simple..   If you'd put it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specifically change the configuration (in Visual Studio) of stdafx.cpp (or whatever source file you have that gets compiled with /Yc) to define the symbol NOW_CREATING_THE_PCH, leaving the symbol undefined for the rest of the source files (which get compiled with /Yu).

That's not something you get out-of-the-box, but if you need to do it just for one project (or a few), it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, the simplest way of solving this problem is to use the `#import` statement with `no_implementation` in the header file which is used to generate the precompiled header (usually StdAfx.h) and re-`#import` the header file into the source file that is used to trigger the generation of the pch with the parameter `implementation_only`. That way the implementation of the wrapper functions are being defined, but only in one place.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but these are *a lot* (hundreds) of sources.  I think I'll go with @Boaz's comment.