# C/C++ Compiler listing what's defined

Tags: c-preprocessor

This question : [Is there a way to tell whether code is now being compiled as part of a PCH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825267/is-there-a-way-to-tell-whether-code-is-now-being-compiled-as-part-of-a-pch) lead me to thinking about this.

Is there a way, *in perhaps only certain compilers*, of getting a C/C++ compiler to dump out the defines that it's currently using?

Edit: I know this is technically a pre-processor issue but let's add that within the term compiler.

Comment: To nitpick: That'd a preprocessor feature.

Comment: How is seeing the output of a preprocessor not meeting what you're trying to do?

Comment: Because ISTM that most compliers these days include the pre-processor within them. I've not done C++ for many years but I don't recall ever running the pre-processor myself manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In GCC

```
g++ -E -dM <file>
```

I would bet it is possible in nearly all compilers.

Comment: I haven't stumbled across the feature in any compiler.  I'm impressed that `gcc` has it.

Answer (score 1):

Boost Wave (a preprocessor library that happens to include a command line driver) includes a [tracing capability](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/wave/doc/tracing_facility.html) to trace macro expansions. It's probably a bit more than you're asking for though -- it doesn't just display the final result, but essentially every step of expanding a macro (even a very complex one).

The [clang preprocessor](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html) is somewhat similar. It's also basically a library that happens to include a command line driver. The preprocessor defines a [`macro_iterator`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html#ad9f55df37ca31d2ee2451c27c7222ddf) type and `macro_begin`/`macro_end` of that type, that will let you walk the preprocessor symbol table and do pretty much whatever you want with it (including printing out the symbols, of course).